# mount point /dev/sdb1/mnt is not a directory

Tags: linux, archlinux

I'm partway through an installation of Arch Linux and, following the online instructions, I'm mounting /dev/sdb1/mnt.

When I input

```
mount /dev/sdb1/mnt
```

it returns

```
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

Using both auto and ext4 (my filesystem type, I'm fairly certain)

```
mount auto /dev/sdb1/mnt
```

I get

```
mount: mount point /dev/sdb1/mnt is not a directory
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 7):

You are missing a space:

```
# right here---v
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

The mount command wants a device and a directory. `/dev/sdb1` is the device, and `/mnt` is the directory.